# Scratched DVD keeps freezin when copying files, even with programs

Tags: data-recovery

I have a dvd with some family photos that is scratched, the problem is that when i try to copy stuff it reaches certain points and freezes, i'm assuming its the scratches / corrupt data.

I've been trying several programs that are supposed to copy corrupt files from damaged media regardless, but they keep freezing when they reach the same points, so no different when with windows.

Is there a way to fix the DVD? Or a really really good program that can do that without freezing / allowing windows to freeze?

Please help, I don't have any copies of the photos and they are irreplaceable.

Comment: depending on how deep the damage is, there are repair options, see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-repair-and-recover-data-from-damaged-cds-or-dvds/

Answer (score 2):

I posted this on a [recent question](https://superuser.com/questions/251982/how-do-i-replace-or-repair-a-broken-os-x-install-disc) that's not really a duplicate. I'm not a shill for the company, just a happy customer.

---

I have successfully used [Novus Fine Scratch Remover](http://www.novuspolish.com/fine_scratch_remover.html) several times.

[image: Novus Fine Scratch Remover]
<sub><sup>Although it would take forever to go through the big jug.</sup></sub>